# how to do text box characters convert to ascii and multiplication in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have a text "vpn123" in my textbox and i want to convert that all the text in the textbox into ASCII and the ASCII value of "123" multiply by 5 and the characters ASCII values multiply by 5 then want to add multiplied values add to the next letter ASCII value.I try to do coding but get nothing.Please help!

```
v => convert to ASCII * 5 = 590       = 590
p => convert to ASCII * 5 = 560 + 590 = 1150
n => convert to ASCII * 5 = 550 + 560 = 1100
1 => convert to ASCII * 5 = 245
2 => convert to ASCII * 5 = 250
3 => convert to ASCII * 5 = 255
```

I Want to Get the answer = '59011501100245250255' in my massage box

how can i solve this problem using c#?

```
        string s = new string(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text).SelectMany(b =>  b.ToString()).ToArray());
        ulong multi = 5;
        ulong pass = multi * Convert.ToUInt64(s);
        MessageBox.Show(" " + pass);
```

Comment: I do not get the part "add multiplied values add to the next letter ASCII value". You example indicates that you add the _previous_ letter's ASCII code, _multiplied by 5_. And what shall happen if the previous character is not a letter?

Comment: Do you need a LINQ solution or is an explicit `for` loop (which would probably be easier to understand in this case) fine?

Comment: If there is a letter before it, its ASCII value needs to be added to the next letter ASCII Value, but if it is a number, Convert to ASCII and multiplying by 5 is enough..

Comment: For Loop Is ok..Its Also easier to me to Understand the code part..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I have made a slight change in the expected method. How to get the answer as below?

Comment: The ASCII value obtained by multiplying the ASCII value of the first letter or number by 5 should be added to the ASCII value obtained by multiplying the ASCII value of the following letter or number by 5. Everything should appear in one line as shown below.
I Want a output as a "59011501700194519952250"in my massage box

Comment: v => convert to ASCII * 5 = 590 = 590,p => convert to ASCII * 5 = 560 = 560 + 590 = 1150,n => convert to ASCII * 5 = 550 = 550 +  1150 = 1700,1 => convert to ASCII * 5 = 245 = 245 + 1700 = 1945,2 => convert to ASCII * 5 = 250 = 250 + 1945 = 1995,3 => convert to ASCII * 5 = 255 = 255 + 1995 = 2250

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution not using LINQ, but a `for` loop, which might be easier to construct and understand:

```
string text = "vpn123";

var result = new StringBuilder();

for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    // multiply character code by 5
    var number = text[i] * 5;
    if (char.IsLetter(text[i]) && i > 0 && char.IsLetter(text[i - 1]))
    {
        // if this character is a letter and the previous one also was a letter,
        // add the multiplied value of the previous letter
        number += text[i - 1] * 5;
    }
    result.Append(number);
}

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Prints: 59011501110245250255